# Fails to use css position

Tags: html, css

I want the **delete** to be at the `right` of the box. How should I do this?

```html
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;">
    name
    <a style="position:relative;right:0%">delete</a>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8n8k3qy/2/)

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3lackRos3/h8n8k3qy/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `float:right` with the delete:

```
<a style="position:relative;float:right;">delete</a>
```

**[Here's the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8n8k3qy/4/).**

Answer (score 1):

Use `position: absolute;` (positions element relative to its container) instead of `position: relative;` (positions element relative to its original position). Additionally, put `position: relative;` on the parent element (so that the link is positioned in relation to it, not some ancestor farther up the tree).

Answer (score 0):

Hi try using float right

```
<a style="position:relative;right:0%;float:right">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right` in `a`

```
<a style="position:relative; float:right">delete</a>
```